# Jboss 7 deployment error: WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed & WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I deployed my application on JBoss EAP 7.2.0 and get the following error:

```
> {
  "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.wm.WorkManager1",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.eis.XUConnectionFactory"
  ],
  "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.clos.clos.env.eis.XUConnectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.eis.XUConnectionFactory]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.clos.clos.env.wm.WorkManager1 is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.wm.WorkManager1]"
  ]
}
```

In my web.xml have config:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>eis/XUConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>wm/WorkManager1</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

commonj.work.WorkManager is in lib commonj-twm.jar and javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory is in java ee 1.5

What should I do with this error?

Please help me, Any help will be appreciated.